# Параллельно отображающий действия html редактор

Tags: html, веб-дизайн, инструменты-разработчика

Подскажите инструмент для веб дизайна при котором действия будут отображаться параллельно, кроме DreamWeaver

Comment: `Веб-дизайн` или `Верстка` все же?

Comment: верстка @palmervan

Comment: Не пойму, что значит «действия будут отображаться параллельно». Это плохо?

Comment: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/09/live-edit-in-phpstorm/

Comment: http://jsbin.com :)

Comment: http://youtu.be/1mZ6nV-dlso

Answer (score 1):

Для автообновления вебстраниц при редактировании CSS есть следующие неплохие инструменты:

1. [CodeKit](http://www.incident57.com/codekit/)
2. [Hammer](http://hammerformac.com/)
3. [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/)

Кроме того в Firefox и в Chrome можно установить плагины, называются они там обычно Autorefresher или Autoreloader. В Опере есть по-умолчанию функция автообновления. Выставляешь в них период автообновления 1 сек. и редактируешь код.